# Как вытащить 1 символ в строке php?

Tags: php, строки

Есть строка `$text="Текс";`

Как вытащить 1 символ?

Пробовал echo `$text[0]` или `$text{0}`

`iconv("UTF-8", "windows-1251", $text[0]);` Вообще не возвращает ничего
`iconv("windows-1251", "UTF-8",  $text[0]);` 
результат
�

Но если `echo $text;` текст норм

Comment: substr($text[0],0,1) �

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mb_substr($text,0,1,'utf8');
```